# Tree Panel 'nodeexpand' event in Extjs6.5 not working

Tags: extjs

I am trying to create a TreePanel is something like a folder explorer. I am trying to find the event when I click the Node Expander (as the following screenshot) in my tree panel.

[image]

Does anyone know what's the correct event?

Here's the code for my view:

```
Ext.define('HDDTest.view.mod.searchDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'searchDetails',
    controller: 'home',
    requires: [
        'HDDTest.view.mod.PreviewPlugins.PreviewPlugin',
        'Ext.grid.*',
        'Ext.data.*',
        'Ext.util.*',
        'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
        'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager'
    ],
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            iconCls: 'icon-tree',
            title: 'Tree',
            collapsible: true,
            height: 300,
            padding:'0 20 0 0',
            rootVisible: false,
            id: 'treePanel',
            name:'treePanel',
            store: {
                type: 'TreeBufferStore'
            },
            listeners: {
                itemclick: 'onNodesSelected',
                nodeexpand  : 'onNodesSelected2' //<== It can not work
            },

            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
                text: 'Representation',
                width: 360,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'text',
                locked: true
            }, {
                text: 'Parents',
                width: 430,
                dataIndex: 'From',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                text: 'NCID',
                width: 430,
                dataIndex: 'ncid',
                sortable: true

            }]
        }
    ]
});
```

I get nothing. How can I do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [itemexpand](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html#event-itemexpand) instead of **nodeexpand** it will work.

I have created an demo you check here how it is working [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26v4)

Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: false,
    root: {
       expanded: true
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'veddocs.json',
        timeout: 300000,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'children'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        itemexpand: function( node, eOpts){//Fires after this Panel has expanded.
           Ext.Msg.alert('Success',`Your node <b>${node.get('text')}</b>  is exapand`);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I find the correct event called  'beforeload' finally. Thanks for your help, Njdhv.